# How can I add service call in SAP B1 SDK?

Tags: sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I want to add service call in SAP B1 SDK but I'm getting the following error message

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp

Error:-5002

Below are sample codes of PHP

```
$oService=$mycomp->GetBusinessObject(191);
$oService->CallType=5;
$oService->CustomerCode="460201";
$oService->subject="Text here";

$oService->Add;
```

Is there any other field which is mandatory

Comment: I usually find that if you can add the same record through the B1 client using the same data, then it will be accepted by DI-API. The SDK help file tells you the mandatory properties also, it indicates CustomerCode and Subject are the only mandatory ones. Have you tried "Subject" instead of "subject"? Is "CallType" a valid OSCT ID?

Comment: huh, does the SAP B1 SDK support non-.Net languages now? What version are you running?