# How to add more than one line in stages of opportunity of SAP B1 in SDK?

Tags: sapb1

I have a problem of to add more than one line in stages of SAP B1 opportunity, when I add one line it will be added successfully but two or more line does not work. Below are my sample codes (PHP)

```
<?php
$oOpport->Lines->LineNum=0;
$oOpport->Lines->MaxLocalTotal=6669;
$oOpport->Lines->StageKey=1;
$oOpport->Lines->Add;


$oOpport->Lines->LineNum=1;
$oOpport->Lines->MaxLocalTotal=10000;
$oOpport->Lines->StageKey=1;
$oOpport->Lines->Add;
?>
```

How can I add more than one line?
Please anyone can help me

Comment: What is your code for two lines?

Comment: Hi Sandra, I updated my code

Comment: Does it simply not work? Is it returning any error after `$oOpport->Add;` ? Does it add only one line?

Comment: It does not add anything. It gives error message Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\......  Error: -5002

Comment: The DI Connection is established properly?

Comment: Yes, because when I use one line it adds opportunity successfully

Comment: Probably it is something like a previous question of yours [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376155/), maybe something mandatory on adding multiple lines. I haven't used php in DI API and this error hasn't appeared on me using .Net

Comment: Sorry, usually I can add any document in PHP with multi lines, but opportunity does not allow to set value like $oOpport->Lines->LineNum=0; for first line and $oOpport->Lines->LineNum=1; for second line as it used in other documents. But it gives the new error com_exception: Error [0x8002000e] Invalid number of parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200946/discussion-between-vyron-paschalidis-and-schadrack-rurangwa).

Comment: Hi all, it was done. the problem was Predicted Closing Date